# Applying the Rule of Five with Inheritance and Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Every example that I've seen which implement the Rule of Five, implements the rule on a class without inheritance and polymorphism (virtual functions).

How can the rule of 5 be applied to the sample code bellow?

The test example uses c-arrays for dynamic objects.  **This is slightly contrived of course in order to have dynamic objects to manage to demonstrate the Rule of Five.** In practice, it could have been anything (FILE ptrs, database handles, etc). Therefore, don't suggest using vector, or turning the exercise into demonstration of the Rule of Zero.

I'd prefer the solution not to use the copy-swap idiom because I find the non-copy-swap method more explicit in the case of non-inheriting classes.  But if one wished to illustrate both methods, that would also be great.

Notes about sample code:

- B inherits from A.
- Both A & B have their own dynamic object to manage (a contrived c-array).
- Class T is a contrived class to have custom type for diagnostic prints. The c-arrays store T elements.
- Class A & B are void of Rule of Five implementation (to be defined by answer)
- The c-arrays have not yet been allocated in the sample code, but of course, they would be at construction based on respective bufferSize.

**Sample Code**

```
//TEST TYPE
class T
{
public:
        T()  { cout << "ctorT" << endl; }
        ~T() { cout << "dtorT" < endl; }

        T(const T& src)             { cout << "copy-ctorT  " << endl; }
        T& operator=(const T& rhs)  { cout << "copy-assignT" << endl; return *this; }
        T(T&& src) noexcept         { cout << "move-ctorT  " << endl; }
        T& operator=(T&& rhs)       { cout << "move-assignT" << endl; return *this; }
}

class A
{
    string nameParent = "A";
    size_t bufferSizeParent = 0;
    T *pBufferParent = nullptr;                 //c-array

public:
    A(string tNameParent, size_t tBufferSizeParent) : nameParent(tNameParent), bufferSizeParent(tBufferSizeParent)
    {
        cout << "ctorA " << nameParent << endl;
    }

    virtual ~A(){ cout << "dtorA " << nameParent << endl; }     
    virtual string getName()                    { return nameParent; }
    virtual void setName(const string name)     { nameParent = name; }
};

class B : public A
{
    string nameChild = "B";
    size_t bufferSizeChild = 0;
    T *pBufferChild = nullptr;              //c-array

public:
    B(string tNameChild, string tNameParent, size_t tBufferSizeChild, size_t tBufferSizeParent) 
    : A(tNameParent, tBufferSizeParent), nameChild(tNameChild), bufferSizeChild(tBufferSizeChild)
    {
        cout << "ctorB " << nameChild << endl;
    }

    ~B(){ cout << "dtorB " << nameChild << endl; }             

    virtual string getName() override final             { return nameChild; }
    virtual void setName(const string name) override final  { nameChild = name; }
};
```

Comment: Are you intending to allocate some `T`s in `A::A` and/or `B::B`? At the moment you have some `T*`s that are never changed from `nullptr`

Comment: Yes, the arrays once allocated at construction, would use T in array. I didn't allocate the arrays on purpose yet, to keep the example flexible.  So people can implement the Rule of Five as they think it should be implemented.  I implemented most of the skeleton code and left the Rule of Five implementation explicitly out.  So everyone has the same skeleton to work from.   I suppose I could have allocated the arrays in the constructor, I don't think it would have impacted the various Rule of Five implementations people may have...

Comment: Replace `T*` with `std::vector<T>`, and get all the copying and stuff for free. If you have a dynamic resource other than memory in mind, implement a RAII class to manage it, and use an instance of that class as a data member.

Comment: As stated, c-arrays were chosen precisely for Rule of Five demonstration purposes. You can't demonstrate the rule of five with vector.  This is a question about how to implement the rule of five, not how to avoid it and use the rule of zero.  There are cases when you can't avoid it.  using c-arrays is slightly contrived, since it can be avoided, but should be sufficient for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is that a class should directly manage **at most one** resource. Other classes have all `default`ed special members, preferably implicitly, but explicitly if they are to be declared in some variation.

Your example becomes

```
struct T;
extern T acquire_T();
extern void release_T(T);

class THandle
{
    T handle;
public:
    THandle() 
      : handle(acquire_T()) {}
    ~THandle() { release_T(handle); }
    THandle(const THandle &) = delete;
    THandle(THandle && other) 
      : handle(other.handle) 
    { other.handle = {}; }
    THandle & operator=(const THandle &) = delete;
    THandle & operator=(THandle && other)
    { std::swap(handle, other.handle); }
}

class A
{
    std::string nameParent = "A";
    std::size_t bufferSizeParent = 0;
    THandle tParent;

public:
    A() {}
    A(std::string tNameParent, std::size_t tBufferSizeParent) : nameParent(tNameParent), bufferSizeParent(tBufferSizeParent)
    { }

    virtual ~A() = default;
    A(const A &) = default;
    A(A &&) = default;
    A & operator=(const A &) = default;
    A & operator=(A &&) = default;

    virtual string getName()                    { return nameParent; }
    virtual void setName(const string name)     { nameParent = name; }
};

class B : public A
{
    std::string nameChild = "B";
    std::size_t bufferSizeChild = 0;
    THandle tChild;

public:
    B() {}
    B(string tNameChild, string tNameParent, size_t tBufferSizeChild, size_t tBufferSizeParent) 
    : A(tNameParent, tBufferSizeParent), nameChild(tNameChild), bufferSizeChild(tBufferSizeChild), bufferChild(std::make_unique(tBufferSizeChild))
    { }

    virtual string getName() override final             { return nameChild; }
    virtual void setName(const string name) override final  { nameChild = name; }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't you also need the custom deleter for `bufferParent` and `bufferChild` declarations?  That is, what will make the later call to `delete[]` instead of just `delete`?

Comment: Chris O, no. Caleth has not implemented the Rule of Five. He followed the Rule of Zero.  unique_ptr is specialized for c-array and will auto call delete[] on the array.  He used unique_ptr for the same reason that some use vector, to avoid manual life cycle management.

Comment: no, the default deleter for `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` calls `delete[]`

Comment: Caleth, thank you for your post but you miss understaood my question.  I'm not trying to avoid using the Rule of Five.  I used c-array on purpose to demonstrate the mechanisms of the Rule of Five... specifically how it would be implemented with inheritance.

Comment: Yes, and I'm suggesting that you as much as possible *don't* write special members

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I was thinking of the `shared_ptr` care, you're totally correct, thanks.